# How to simulate user input to std::cin for a mcve?

Tags: c++, user-input, cin

I want to prepare a mcve for a colleague, but to run the example some complicated user input from `std::cin` is required that I'd like to include in my example code. I tried to read from a `string` instead of `std::cin`, but it didnt work. Simplified example:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::string test_input{"1.2 3 a"};        
    double a;
    //std::cin >> a;    
    test_input >> a;
    std::cout << a;
}
```

results in a incredibly long error message starting with

```
prog.cc: In function 'int main()':
prog.cc:8:16: error: no match for 'operator>>' (operand types are 'std::__cxx11::string' {aka 'std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>'} and 'double')
     test_input >> a;
     ~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~
```

How can I simulate user input to `std::cin`?

Comment: Do you need to include this programatically? Maybe a separate file/piece of text would be easier?

Comment: Was this question opened and closed solely to direct users to the duplicate? Or was it an actual question that you only realized was a duplicate after opening?

Comment: @scohe001 first i didnt find the dupe, started writing the question, found the dupe, finsished writing it anyhow, got a little annoyed by the fact that i cannot vote for dupes, voted anyhow, think it would be nice to have a question titled like this, but the answer answer has a slightly differente scope, nevertheless the top answer is a nice match...

Comment: @scohe001 dont know if I should reopen, delete or whatever, thought I just wait for the downvotes ;)

Comment: My first thought was that it was related to hunting for secret hats.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux of course i dont want to collect the rep, I just dont know how to make it a community question (if thats possible). And I wont give away the glasses anymore :P

Comment: @user463035818 Ha. Guess it's time to delete [my meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/377823/2602718) then, I had it all completely wrong. Glad you found what you were looking for!

Comment: Deliberate duplicate questions acting as sign posts is fine, if the title is helpfully different.

Comment: Nice shades, man.